# How can I install the SQL Server PowerShell module on an offline machine?

Tags: sql-server, installation, powershell, patching, automation

I have some SQL Server machines that cannot connect to any external sites.

I have been using PowerShell more and more when managing databases, so I definitely need this module to be installed so that I can use my PowerShell routines.

It has been proven difficult to install the SQL Server module on those offline machines.

When I try to install the module:

[image]

the `SqlServer` module asks for the [NuGet module package](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/197509/22336):

[image]

I then get this ocean of red letters and the following error message as you can see on the picture below:

> WARNING: Unable to download from URI
>   'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
>
> WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check
>   your internet connection. PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider :
>   Unable to find package provider 'NuGet'.
>
> It may not be imported yet.
>   Try 'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable'.
>
> At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7415
>   char:30
>   + ... tProvider = PackageManagement\Get-PackageProvider -Name $script:NuGet ...

[image]

What is the workaround for this PowerShell module installation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PowerShell has a built-in mechanism for this which should be easier than [the previous answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/264973/22336).

From an Internet-connected computer, run `Save-Module sqlserver -path c:\tmp` (substitute whatever path you want for the module to be saved to). This will save the module to a directory of the same name in `c:\tmp` (`c:\tmp\SqlServer`).

Then, copy that whole directory to your target computer(s). You have a couple options for the destination, depending upon how you want to make it available to users. On PowerShell 5.1 and older look at the paths in the `PSModulePath` environment variable. On my system, I have:

```
> $env:psmodulepath.split(";")
C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
C:\Program Files\Intel\Wired Networking\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
```

To make the module available to all users, I'd put it in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`. For just myself, it'll go into `C:\Users\MYNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

These paths may be a bit different if you're running [PowerShell Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_Core_6.0) or PowerShell 7; you'd look at one or more of the paths in `$PSGetPath`.

From here, you should be able to run `Import-Module sqlserver` successfully.

Shameless plug: If you're doing a lot of SQL Server administration via PowerShell (and I heartily encourage it!), you should be checking out the [`dbatools`](https://dbatools.io) module.

Comment: this is amazing, nice to meet you `Save-Module`, +1 thanks for posting, I had to go through that rough path to get it done, this is way easier, I am glad I posted!!!

Comment: ah but I am not sure about the Nuget thing, anyway that is dealt with in the [other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/264973/22336)

Comment: Nuget shouldn't be needed with the `save-module` approach.

Comment: I have installed per this but when I do sqlcmd -? nothing comes up. Does it have to be SQL standard or higher?

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I got it done. I got the information from several articles online, like [this](https://www.intrepidintegration.com/powershell/how-to-get-psget-working-with-no-net/), and [this](https://sqlserverunlimited.com/2019/08/01/powershell-install-sqlserver-module-offline/).

I am very thankful for the people who made those articles available.

---

So looking on another computer (that does have Internet access) ensure that the NuGet package is installed and explore that folder. We can see:

[image]

[image]

So if we copy that DLL file over to the machine without Internet access, and store it in the same folder structure, just make sure you close and reopen you [PowerShell ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) program.

If now you try the `install-module -name sqlserver` again, you will still get a message about a repository needed:

[image]

And then the error message below:

[image]

So you better [manually download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7#using-manual-download-to-acquire-a-package) the `SqlServer` module package currently from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17224).

> To download manually, click on Download the raw nupkg file. A copy of
>   the package is copied to the download folder for your browser with the
>   name ..nupkg.

There are some instructions [here](https://sqlserverunlimited.com/2019/08/01/powershell-install-sqlserver-module-offline/):

1. Download module on a system that has access to Internet from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18080)
2. This will download a folder in .nupkg format. Rename the folder to .zip extension.
3. Copy the zip folder to any location on the target server (in my case `c:\sql_install` and unzip it into a folder - rename the folder to  `sqlserver`
4. go to PowerShell and run the following script:

   ```
   $env:PSModulePath
   ```

   [image]
5. from the above result you can see my path, and based on that I copied the `sqlserver` folder - from `2` to the following locations:

   > C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;
   >
   > C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;
   >
   > C:\Program Files> (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
6. Close and reopen powershell ise (always as administrator)
7. Check in the powershell ise -> Modules - if `sqlserver` is there:

   [image]
8. If it is not - then something went wrong - otherwise you should be able now to run

   ```
   Import-Module sqlserver
   ```
9. And as I test in PowerShell:

   Get-SqlAgent -ServerInstance my_server_name

   [image]

If it worked fine, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The TLS settings need to be updated.

1. Run Powershell as Administrator and run the following commands prior to installing the SQLServer Module.

   a. `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

   b. `Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force`
2. Once installed, you may now install the SLQServer Module.

   `Install-Module -Name SqlServer`

The module should now install.

Comment: That worked for me, thank you so much @mustaccio and @neil-bunderson!
On a machine running PS v5.1.19041.1682 / Windows v10.0.19042 N/A Build 19042.

It looks like the solution is _highly_ dependent on the actual OS & PS version...